# JFreechart - How to set Domain Axis range?

Tags: range, jfreechart

I'm newbie in JFreechart. I've a dataset which contains more records(>50 ) i.e (the X-values are products and Y-Axis are quantity) , in the chart i want to display only first 15 records in the X-axis. I'm using CategoryAxis like.

```
final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
 final CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
```

Anyone please guide me to do this.?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be an axis problem. One simple expedient would be to add only the desired records, but [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/SlidingCategoryDataset.html) would allow you to `setFirstCategoryIndex(0)` and `setMaximumCategoryCount(15)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now i'm able to get first 15 records, but the tick marks& labels are generated for all records in X-axis. I want to restrict the ticks also to 15 count..

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.