# JFreeChart: Bar chart X axis labels overlapping with large datasets

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm facing the below issue while using JFreeChart for creating bar chart with relatively large dataset:

Bar chart generated with overlapping X-axis labels. I have tried positioning the labels vertical, still no help. Please provide the best possible way to solve this issue. Code snipped below:

```
CategoryDataset categoryDataSet = getBarDataset();
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("TITLE", "X-LABEL","Y-LABEL", categoryDataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
barChart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
barChart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis().setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(4);
jpg = Image.getInstance(im, null);
document.add(jpg);
```

**Update:**
As per the suggestion from @trashgod, I've used SlidingCategoryDataset indexing from 0 to the column count. When the column count is large(50 here), the X-Label's are overlapping. When the column count is set to a lower number, it's working fine. I want to find a solution for large column size. Importantly, I need to export the chart image to pdf. Please help me in arriving to a feasible solution. Thanks!

```
    private static void createBarChart() throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE_LOCN));
        writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
        document.open();
        CategoryDataset categoryDataset = createDataset();
        int colCount = categoryDataset.getColumnCount();
        SlidingCategoryDataset slidingCategoryDataSet = new SlidingCategoryDataset(categoryDataset, 0, colCount);
        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("TITLE", "X-LABEL","Y-LABEL", slidingCategoryDataSet, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        barChart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_90);
        barChart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis().setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(4);
        java.awt.Image im = barChart.createBufferedImage(400, 400);
        Image jpg = Image.getInstance(im, null);
        jpg.scaleToFit(400, 400);
        document.add(jpg);
        document.close();
        writer.close();
    }

    private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
            dataset.addValue(i, "R", "C" + i);
        }
        return dataset;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20SlidingCategoryDataset).

Comment: @trashgod I've tried it, but still the same issue.

Comment: `int colCount = categoryDataset.getColumnCount();
SlidingCategoryDataset slidingCategoryDataSet = new SlidingCategoryDataset(categoryDataset, 0, colCount);
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("TITLE", "X-LABEL","Y-LABEL", slidingCategoryDataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);`

Comment: Where do you set the count and index, for [examplke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17163915/230513)? If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: @trashgod, Edited the question with your suggestion of using SlidingCategoryDataset.

Comment: Your application has to set the count and index as desired, say in a slider or spinner. As your update now mentions a PDF, `SlidingCategoryDataset` is not a feasible approach .

Comment: @trashgod How can I achieve this in a pdf? I'm stuck on this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Smaller font? More pixels?

Comment: More pixels seems to a good idea, but how can we implement that here?

Comment: I've summarized our colloquy below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a large number of categories, specifying vertical labels via [`setCategoryLabelPositions()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html#setCategoryLabelPositions-org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions-) is a good choice for maximizing legibility. Arbitrary [`CategoryLabelPositions`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryLabelPositions.html) are supported.

In an interactive chart, [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/SlidingCategoryDataset.html), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20SlidingCategoryDataset), allows your application to set the count and starting index of visible categories as desired, perhaps using a slider or spinner, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17163915/230513).

> How can I achieve this in a PDF?…More pixels seems a good idea, but how can we implement that here?

In a fixed size context with a given number of categories, you can optimize the size of the chart image via [`createBufferedImage()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#createBufferedImage-int-int-), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20createBufferedImage), or [`Image.scaleToFit()`](https://coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/itext-2.1.7/com/lowagie/text/Image.html#scaleToFit(float,%20float)). For yet larger datasets, it may be possible to create multiple linked charts in a domain specific way, e.g. by year or subsidiary.